# Correct way to undo the past few git commits including a merge?

Tags: git

My team is working with git for the first time and has really messed up our git remote due to our inexperience. I'm trying to help educate them on git to solve the problem in the long term, but in the meantime, the commits that have been made are totally wrong. We haven't made very much progress at all, and I don't see the value in retaining these commits when they could cause confusion/additional problems down the line.

The most recent commit was a merge between the master branch and a second branch that one of the team members unintentionally created. If I try to revert, git states that I must be using the -m flag, but I'm not sure whether I should be reverting or trying to rebase in this case, or how I would do it given the structure of the past couple of commits.

What is the best way to resolve this issue and how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Is it possible to see `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`? You can remove sensitive info from the graph log. Do you want to just throw commits away? Using revert instead of reset or rebase will save you the trouble of trying to sync everyone up, because all that they have to do is a normal fetch and merge. If you force people to sync with a reset or rebased branch, that is feasible, but could be a lot of work to coordinate.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: @Cupcake, I'll check it out :] Thanks!

gnat, Thank you; That helps!

Comment: Jsess, @Cupcake was asking for some more information about the structure of your git commits so that it would be possible to address exactly what is necessary to fix your repository.

Comment: @MichaelT I was unable to access my workstation for a while and didn't want to simply ignore the comment - thanks for letting me know.

I commented on Dr. Ibb's answer with what I did to attempt to resolve the issue - I tried resetting and then force pushing my change, and that appears to have worked.

Answer (score 7):

To undo the merge, you can do

```
git checkout master
git revert -m 1 [SHA of the merge commit]
git push
```

This will create and push a new commit which reverts all changes that were merged in.

It's also possible to alter master's history so that it appears as if the merge never happened, but I wouldn't recommend it. Your teammates would have trouble when they try to pull master and the history is different. Also it's easy to revert a revert commit if you reverted the wrong changes, but if you alter mater's history, it's harder to undo that.

Comment: After doing this, do I need to simply revert the additional non-merge commits?

I'd heard something about reverting merges giving incorrect feedback with respect to the commits that were originally merged together. Are there any side-effects to this that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Were the other commits part of the merge or separate? If separate then yes, you'd need to `git revert [SHA]` each one.

Comment: I've managed to successfully revert the merge, but reverting additional commits afterward fails with "could not revert <commit>." After looking up the error, I'm seeing that I need to "resolve the merge" before doing the revert, but I'm having trouble understanding what needs to be resolved.

It's clear to me that when you're pulling files that conflict you need to resolve merges because you're "moving forward," but because revert seems to be an undo, I'm not sure I see what merge I need to resolve before reverting.

Comment: In some cases you can avoid conflicts by reverting the most recent change first, then the next most recent, etc. But if there are good commits mixed in with bad commits and they touch the same files, there may be "real" conflicts that you need to resolve manually.

Comment: What exactly creates the conflicts? It seems that if you were to revert a commit, the next commit on the "stack" would be the most "recent" one and shouldn't have any conflicts at all. I'm having trouble conceptualizing what is creating conflict states when reverting.

Comment: @Jsess This command creates a new commit that is the exact reverse of the SHA given to it.  If any of the commits that from after the original merge happened to touch the same lines, the conflict is:  when `revert` looks at the code it's trying to revert, the code no longer matches the state the code was in immediately after the original merge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the git reset command. If you run git log it will show you a commit history for your repo. Then run git reset --hard HEAD-number of commits you'd like to go back.

Documentation here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: I'd seen that but was unsure how to get these changes to apply to the remote branch so that they could be passed on to each of the team's local repos. Do you have any additional information that might apply to that?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You may find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository

Comment: I see - if I'm understanding correctly, it looks like I could reset to the commit that I wanted, then force push to the remote branch.

Would this have the behavior that I was expecting? As far as best practice, is this or revert preferred?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've had to deal with this but I believe that doing a force push will get you where you want to be. reset --hard is sort of a last resort option, as it will wipe out pretty much everything, if I recall correctly. git revert is a little less aggressive and will show as an additional item in the repo's history, so you can revert the revert if needed.

Comment: If you find it easier to pick a commit to go back to, but also want the safer option, you could do `git reset --soft [good SHA]`, `git commit` and `git push`. That would push a new change that reverts everything after the good SHA.

Comment: You may also find this helpful (especially the reset and revert sections): http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/

Comment: I just tried using git reset --hard <commit> and force pushing, and it did exactly what I was looking to do. The commit tree is now back at the commit I reset to and there is no previous record of the commits we wanted to drop.

I'm curious as to how this behavior is created - it seems like a reset drops commits in the local git repo (as opposed to creating a branch), but why does forcing a push remove previous records of commits? Why does it overwrite commits? I understand that resetting deletes commits, so it doesn't make sense to put the new commit on top of the existing tree. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a git master so I'm not sure why it works the way it does, but you may find the Discussion section here helpful: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Glad to hear that you got where you wanted to be.

Comment: What's interesting about git is you have your own local master branch which can diverge from the remote git server's master. When you run `git reset --hard [SHA]` your local master branch will point to that SHA. When you force push master the remote server's master branch will point to that SHA too.

Comment: By the way since you altered master's history, I think your teammates will get errors when they `git pull`. They could do `git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master` to overwrite their master branch with your new one, or just delete their local repos and do a fresh clone.

Comment: Yeah, I advised them to do a reclone, but I hadn't considered the fetch-reset. Thank you so much for the help!